# Update values in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a react js application which is responsible to update a status of every user:

```js
function App() {
  const tableData = [
      { name: 'Tanner Linsley', angry: true }
    , { name: 'Bob Dylan', angry: false }
  ];


  const handler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

  const columns = [
    {
      Header: 'Name',
      accessor: 'name' // String-based value accessors!
    },
    {
      Header: 'Angry',
      id:'s',
      accessor: (r) => <input checked={r.angry} onChange={handler} type='checkbox'/>,
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactTable
        data={tableData}
        columns={columns}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Inside the table appears the angry status which should be updated, but now if i want to change the status i can not update it and the checkboxes still with previous values. 
 Why i can not update the values and how to solve the issue?
 demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-demo-forked-upn1vt

Comment: It sounds like you're just looking for the `useState` hook.  Store values in state, use the state setter to update that state.  This should be covered by introductory tutorials to React.

Comment: @David, i undertsand this, but how to change the chacked state only for the user that was selected? Because now the state come from the array.

Comment: You would use some unique identifier to determine which record in the array to change.  Currently it looks like the `name` property is that identifier.  So you can pass that value to `handler` as an argument and then use that value to find and update the record in state.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `useState` hook in order to locally store the state of the array and then use - I guess - the name as an identifier to filter the element to be changed.

```
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([
    { name: "Tanner Linsley", angry: true },
    { name: "Bob Dylan", angry: false }
  ]);

  const handler = (e, name) => {
    let newTableData = [...tableData];
    let index = newTableData.findIndex((obj) => obj.name === name);
    newTableData[index].angry = e.target.checked;
    setTableData(newTableData);
  };
```

input `onChange` method should be a little bit different in order to pass the name as an argument.

```
   <input
      checked={r.angry}
      onChange={(e) => handler(e, r.name)}
      type="checkbox"
    />
```

See [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-demo-forked-v7jihg?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: i noticed that this method could be expensive  because my list of data is long and to loop the list again to find that item will be very expensive in terms of productivity. Is there possible to set the name for example when user check the checkbox and after that to compare it inside `checked={r.angry}` like to check if the user checked that name then to apply the new status. Could you help with this please?

Comment: i'm not sure if i understood it. one possible alternative solution would be to create a second array with all the names that are checked